# Return Only Most Recent Instance of Item From Query (Where Multiple Instances Exist)

Tags: sql, duplicates, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have written the following subquery, which is returning instances of item counts from my application's log table.

The idea is that from this subquery I will be pulling information on item counts from a specific date, to be compared to the same information from a different date - info such as, for a given location on the system, what the latest quantity of all items counted within it was.

```
select 
    LOCATION, 
    ITEM,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN ACTION = 'COUNT-OK' 
        THEN QUANTITY 
        ELSE QUANTITY * CHANGE --If ACTION <> 'OK', then we need to adjust the quantity
    END) AS QuantityCalc,
    DATE_TIME,
from LOG_TABLE
    where ACTION IN ('COUNT-ADJ','COUNT-OK')
    AND (CAST(DATE_TIME AS DATE) = @CountDate) --Declared elsewhere
group by LOCATION, ITEM, DATE_TIME
order by DATE_TIME desc
```

My issue is with the rows returned. Because these are application logs, there is a row for each count being done on the system, so only the most recent 'QuantityCalc' for a given item in a location would be accurate.

I need a way to return only the most recent instance of a count happening (where the LOCATION and ITEM values are the same). I am using a SUM in the main query which is pulling the QuantityCalc value from this subquery to find the total Quantity by Item and Location per specific count (to compare them side by side).  This is currently being thrown off by instances such as the below.

I've attached an example image of what this query returns. My issue is with Item2 in Location B and Item3 in location C, and I'd be looking for the query to ONLY return rows 2, 3, 5 and 8 (including header).

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the sample dataset as well for LOG_TABLE. Why are you doing the SUM if you just need the most recent item, you can use ROW_NUMBER() function to achieve it.

Comment: You're right about the SUM - as I am pulling one line per item/location, I shouldn't need it. I'm not familiar with ROW_NUMBER() but will look into it and add an update. Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running. Is this SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-filter the logs for the latest row per location/item tuple, then aggregate. We would typically use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows in a subquery:

```
select 
    LOCATION, 
    ITEM,
    sum(case when ACTION = 'COUNT-OK' then QUANTITY else QUANTITY * CHANGE end) AS QuantityCalc,
    DATE_TIME,
from (
    select l.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by LOCATION, ITEM order by date_time desc) AS RN
    from LOG_TABLE
    where ACTION IN ('COUNT-ADJ','COUNT-OK') and CAST(DATE_TIME AS DATE) = @CountDate
) l
where RN = 1
group by LOCATION, ITEM, DATE_TIME
order by DATE_TIME desc
```

Side note: the filtering on `date_time` can probably be optimized; rather than casting your column to `date`, we can check it directly against a range defined from the date parameter. The syntax of date arithmetic widely varies across databases (and you did not well which one you are using), but in standard SQL that would be:

```
DATE_TIME >= @CountDate and DATE_TIME < @CountDate + interval '1' day
```